# How to setup security realm on tomcat when using tomcat jdbc connection pool?

Tags: java, jdbc, tomcat8

I am using tomcat jdbc connection pool in tomcat 8:

```
PoolProperties p = new PoolProperties();
...
org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.DataSource( p );
```

But I am also using security Realm for login in server.xml:

```
<Realm className="org.apache.catalina.realm.DataSourceRealm"
...
or <Realm  className="org.apache.catalina.realm.JDBCRealm" 
...
```

But it says:

```
SEVERE: Unable to create initial connections of pool.
com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLNonTransientConnectionException: Could not create connection to database server. Attempted reconnect 3 times. Giving up.
```

How should I configure and use it then?

Rob

Comment: add the configuration of your pool jdbc/myDB

Comment: I have the connection url, username, password, it won't do it in server.xml